# React Apexchart

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

How to correctly display large amount of data on ReactApexChart , Bar Chart. At image below, I am passing 552 entries. When amount of entries under 50 everything displays just fine, above this number starts look like a hell and performance is getting low. I am using React Js Class Component.

```js
this.state = {
  series: [{
    name: props.name,
    data: props.chartValue,
  }, ],
  options: {
    grid: {
      row: {
        colors: ["#D6EAF8 ", "#D6EAF8"],
      },
    },
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      height: 350,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        borderRadius: 4,
        horizontal: true,
        colors: {
          ranges: [{
            from: 0,
            to: Number.MAX_VALUE,
            color: "#29ABE2",
          }, ],
          backgroundBarColors: [],
          backgroundBarOpacity: 1,
          backgroundBarRadius: 0,
        },
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function(val) {
        return val + ` min`;
      },
      offsetX: 15,
      style: {
        fontSize: "12px",
        colors: ["#FFFFFF"],
      },
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: props.ids,
      labels: {
        style: {
          colors: [],
          fontSize: "15px",
          fontWeight: 500,
        },
      },
    },
    yaxis: {
      categories: props.differenceInTime,
      labels: {
        style: {
          colors: [],
          fontSize: "15px",
          fontWeight: 500,
        },
      },
      axisTicks: {
        show: true,
        borderType: "solid",
        color: "#78909C",
        width: 10,
        offsetX: 0,
        offsetY: 0,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

```html
<div id="chart">
  <ReactApexChart options={this.state.options} series={this.state.series} type="bar" />
</div>
```

[Here is 552 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDaIZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

why put max integer for the colors? That could be a performance issue

ranges: [{
from: 0,
to: **Number.MAX_VALUE**,
color: "#29ABE2",
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).